# Devise session timeout even I set the timeout_in parameter to 20.years

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis, devise

I have trouble with session's timeout only in production environment, Heroku.
Even I set the `timeout_in` in `config/initializers/devise.rb` to `20.years`, and checked that the cookie's expireation is in 2038, but forced to logout when I do nothing for about 15 minutes or so.

```
config.timeout_in = 20.years
```

This App uses Devise and manage session data with `cache_store` below.

```
# config/application.rb
config.session_store :cache_store, key: "_myapp_session_#{Rails.env}", 
expire_after: 20.years


# config/environments/development.rb
if Rails.root.join('tmp', 'caching-dev.txt').exist?
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.cache_store = :redis_cache_store, { driver: :hiredis, url: "redis://redis:6379/0" }
  config.public_file_server.headers = {
    'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{2.days.to_i}"
  }
else
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.cache_store = :null_store
end


# config/environments/production.rb
config.cache_store = :redis_cache_store, { driver: :hiredis, url: ENV['REDIS_URL'] }
```

Do you have any knowledge why this happens?
Here's the versions

```
Rails 5.2.1.1
Devise 4.5.0
```

Thank you for reading!

Comment: I have similar issues with my production environment, the problem was caused by usage of the same Redis database for session storage and cache storage.

Comment: As a suggestion, you may try to use some additional gem (to setup Redis as Rails session storage). And put app cache and session into separate Redis databases:  `redis://redis:6379/0` for cache and `redis://redis:6379/1` for sessions etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should put `devise.rb` under `config/initializers` folder. What you described suggests Rails did not pick up custom `timeout_in` during its bootstrap.

See https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-models for Devise setup.

See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html#railties-lib-rails-application-rb if you want to know how rails bootstrap works and why this config should be in `config/initializers` folder.

Comment: kasperite

thanks for your comment!
Well, that's my mistake that the `devise.rb` is correctly in `config/initializers` directory. I fix the question. sorry..

Comment: that's strange, did you 1) try to restart server and 2) check if a different `timeout_in` is set in user model?I can't see any other possible reasons, based on what you posted anw

Comment: yes.

and I also checked that `User.first.timeout_in` in production returned `20 years`, so the config should be picked up.

Comment: right...Do you override `timedout?` method in user model?That's my next guess. The whole timeoutable module is around two main methods `timeout_in` and `timedout?` as I recall

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply kasperite! I'm really happy for your kindness!

Well, no... I don't add any methods with that name in any model in my app.

Comment: Now I realize that I'm using cloudflare as DNS between heroku and clients.

Could that be the reason?

Comment: I'm not familiar with how cloudflare manages DNS but worth checking since this is prod only issue

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if you have a `~/config/initializers/session_store.rb` config that may be overriding your devise setting. Code might look something like this:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, {
  key: "_#{some-session-name-here}_session",
  expire_after: 15.minutes
}
```

Note that your app uses Rails 5.2.1.1, and `session_store.rb` was removed in Rails 5.1. `session_store` config is still valid, but it does not automatically generate, etc.